# Differentiating between forms - Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm using multiple html on my page.

```
<form id="form1">
 <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form id="form2">
 <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted I am access the data as follows:bar

```
var bar=$(this).find('input[name=foo]').val();
```

That works fine, but let's say I want to change the form data back on the html page after I have processed the submitted data. How do I reference the form which was submitted?

Something like:

```
$(this).$('#foo').val('Hello');
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(this).find('input[name=foo]').val('Hello');`

Comment: Why wouldn't you still have a reference to the form in `this`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ajax call, you can store a reference to the form before submitting:

```
var form = $(this);
$.ajax (...).done(function (){
    form.find(...).val (...)
});
```

Comment: Fantastic - that worked. I presumed that '$(this).find' would only work when getting the values form the form. I did not think that it was a reference. What exactly is the '.find' part of that statement, just so that I better understand how this work. Many thanks!

Comment: The `find` part is a method of the jQuery object that gets created by calling `$(this)`.